# How do I use memcache in a custom block?

Tags: blocks, caching

I have installed and configured memcache.
I have not got any single tutorial of memcache with custom block. I want to understand how memcache can be integrated with a custom block and views.

Comment: If you follow the Memcached module readme, it will offset the cache bins from Drupal (database based) to memcache for you.

Comment: * you need to add the common settings to settings.php for this to take effect.

Comment: Can you please send me the details of the drupal code for setting file

Comment: Its in the readme.

Comment: Suppose i create a block with machine name 'my_custom_block' , now i want to keep this block data into memcache.

Then can you please tell me what setting needs to be done

Comment: The readme has all the setup/configuration needed to enable memcache.

Comment: Readme tells only about enable the memcache, but not in more details like how to create block with memcache setting.

if you know any tutorial then please give me URL.

Comment: There is no setting in the UI, all the settings are in the module readme about how to set the cache bins.